# Multiple Monitors with Windows7 working, but very slow

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, performance, graphics-card

I have 4 Monitors on 2 graphics cards under windows 7.

- GeForce GT 230 PCIe
- GeForce 6200 PCI

My system is a quadcore @ 2.66 GHz with 8GB RAM.
The monitors attached to the GT230 works perfectly. Those attached to the 6200 are slow, and even when I just try to move a simple window, it "drags" and stutters...

I have installed the latest drivers and tried disabling the fancy GUI stuff but it didn't make any difference.
I used XP before and everything worked fine, no performance problems whatsoever.

Is there anything I can do to increase performance or am I missing some options I have to enable?

Answer (score 1):

the 6200 is a device from 2004.  It does not support DirectX 10, which is used by windows 7 and Vista's Aero interface.. Your probably pushing that graphics card too hard, running two monitors off of it.  (especially if its the rare PCI version, and not the PCI-E version)

What happens if you right click on the desktop, choose personalize, and pick one of the "basic" themes?  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's using the default VGA drivers for that video card instead of the graphic card's drivers.

Comment: Yes, it really looks that way, but the system manager says the driver is loaded. It's the same for both cards though.